# PHP and SMTP server

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

My simple code below:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: info@mail.com \r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: test@mail.com' . "\r\n";

$subject = "Information";

if (mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    $mail_status = "success";
} else {
    $mail_status = "fail";
}

if ($mail_status == "success") echo '{"status":"success"}';
```

How can I support SMTP support?

Comment: Simple Google search should reveal the answer for this question. Have u searched Google and stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

As You mentioned PHPMailer in tags. You can use PHPMailer Class for this process.

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, 
    //gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Source: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp

Answer (score 0):

SMTP server has to be configured on server, but by PHP, which is a programming language. Ask Server admin to provide you SMTP details.

SMTP information can be set in `php.ini` or via `ini_set()`

Example:

```
ini_set("SMTP","smtp.example.com" );
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'user@example.com');
```

By the way, if you require SMTP Authentication, `mail()` does not support it. Try to use other PHP mail library such as SwiftMailer or PHPMailer.

Comment: I know that the SMTP details but I want to provide SMTP support to the code. I added $host = "mail.example.com"; but not solved.

Comment: `$host` is just a variable. As I said, set it via `ini_set()`